# ¿como evitar while(1)?

Tags: c, bucles, while, fibonacci

Esta función sirve para saber si un numero pertenece o no a la sucesion de fibonacci: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 ...

Me gustaria saber como la podría reescribir sin hacer uso de la declaracion `while(1)` y sus correspondientes `break`. Mi objetivo mas o menos es que quede algo así:

```
bool es_Fibo(int n){
  bool fibo = false;
  int a = 0, b = 1;
  int c;

  if(n==0||n==1){
        printf("es fibo\n");
        fibo = true;
    }else{
    while(1){ //while(____)
      c = a + b;
      a = b;
      b = c;
      if(c == n){
        printf("es fibo\n");
            fibo = true;
        break; //quitar el break
      }
      if(c > n){
        printf("no es fibo\n");
            fibo = false;
        break; //quitar el break
      }
    }
  }
  return fibo;
}
```

pero no se como traducir el `while(1)` a una condición para que se repita el bucle.

Comment: Los dos break están "al final" del bucle, después de evaluarlos no cambias ningún valor. Simplemente pon las condiciones, combinadas y negadas, en el while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bien, tu quieres que el while termine cuando se cumpla que:

`c == n` o `c > n`

Por ello si pones como condición

`c < n`

consigues que esos casos donde buscas hacer break el bucle termine su ejecución, recuerda que son casos excluyentes y por tanto cuando se de alguna de las dos condiciones mencionadas, el while se ejecutará esa última vez, con su correspondiente if, obteniendo el comportamiento deseado.

```
bool es_Fibo(int n) {
    bool fibo = false;
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    int c = a + b;

    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        printf("es fibo\n");
        fibo = true;
    }
    else {
        while(c < n) {
            c = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = c;

            if (c == n) {
                printf("es fibo\n");
                fibo = true;
            }

            if (c > n) {
                printf("no es fibo\n");
                fibo = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return fibo;
}
```